# Compute product with varying end index

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to compute the product with a varying end index, but I'm not getting the result I expect:

```
from sympy.abc import n, k
from sympy import IndexedBase, Product

g = IndexedBase('g')

gg = {g[0]: 1, g[1]: 2, g[2]: 3, g[3]: 4, g[4]: 5, g[5]: 6}

my_product = Product(g[n]**-1, (n, 0, k-1))
result = list()

for i in range(len(gg)):
    s = {k: i, **gg}    # substitions
    result.append(my_product.evalf(subs=s))

print(result)
```

The result is:

```
[1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000]
```

The expected result is:

```
[1.00000000000000, 1.00000000000000, 0.500000000000000, 0.166666666666667, 0.0416666666666667, 0.00833333333333333]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what evalf should do here but you can get the result I think you want with

```
result.append(my_product.subs(k, i).doit().subs(gg))
```

With that I get:

```
[1, 1, 1/2, 1/6, 1/24, 1/120]
```

Comment: This works as well: <code>result.append(my_product.subs({k: i}).evalf(subs=gg))</code>.  Potentially the index needs to be substituted into the expression first, but g[i] can be substituted.